# Webpack VSTS Extension Task: "Configuration file found but no entry configured"

Tags: webpack, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Following up on this question at SO:
[Webpack configuration file found but no entry configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357584/webpack-configuration-file-found-but-no-entry-configured)
where the answer was to export your webpack config object.

Thing is... I am exporting it and getting the same error.

I am using the Webpack VSTS Task Extension from Dealogic in VSTS and here is the error log:

[Webpack VSTS Extension Error: No entries found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOxhM.png)

Here's my webpack config
[Webpack config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLCrd.png)

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

### UPDATE:

I debugged the production config by running webpack locally with the production config (as suggested in the commentary below) and discovered the following:
There was resulting [path mismatches when running in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlCVQ.png) (The actual existing path is *C:\Git\WebX\ProjectRootFolder\Content ...*, not *C:\Git\WebX\Content\ ...* )which also should explain the errors in the build step.

So I used [path.resolve in config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iI1E.png) to resolve the absolute paths to entry files. This [solved the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnEmD.png) in the local run.

But when pushing this up to VSTS and running the build it still resolves in [the same error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjjfQ.png).

Comment: What's the result if you run webpack command with that config file in local machine?` node_modules\.bin\webpack --config webpack.production.config.js` Do you check the source version of that build? Set system.debug variable to true and queue build, then share the log on the OneDrive.

Comment: Thank you starian chen-MSFT for your help and it did help to some extent in debugging the build task and to pin point the issue. Me and my colleague have a solution which I will describe as an answer down below,

Answer (score 0):

**Webpack Module Location is 'unsetting' the config location**

The issue has now been solved and the issue and solution was, as far as we can see this:

**The Case:**

We had two config files for webpack:

- webpack.config.json
- webpack.production.config.json

In the [VSTS Webpack Task setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svaM9.png), *webpack config location* and *webpack module location* was set.

**The Cause of the issue:**

What we are pretty sure happened was that, when we set both *webpack config location* and *webpack module location*, Webpack started to either unset the config location setting or (the more likely) look for the *webpack.production.config.json* elsewhere than from our working folder (probably from the webpack module location but this is not 100% sure). When Webpack did not find the production config file it started to look for the default name for a webpack config file (which is webpack.config.js).

Since we had our development config file named to the conventional default name webpack.config.js it found that file and was happy to continue.

But in development we ran webpack as a gulp plugin and the entries was given through the gulp stream, which meant that we did not have any explicitly declared entries in our development config.

Thats why we got the error message ["Config file found but no entries..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jh6q.png) no matter how we formulated our entry strings. The Webpack Task logged out the settings "*webpack.production.config.json*" but after that accually found the development config file. Unfortunatly I interpreted that log as webpack was working with the production config file which was not the case.

**The Solution:**

Our solution to the issue (and to avoid the confusion we had) was the following steps:

- Unset the webpack module location to be empty (This way webpack found our production config file)
- When using several config files: name your webpack config files "webpack.development.config.js" and "webpack.production.config.js" (or anything descriptive other than the default name webpack.config.js). This would have caused it to fail instead of giving the impression that the file (the file we expected anyway ...) was found.

**Worth mentioning**
[The part of the log message (marked in green here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqqxP.png) does only log out your settings. So when the message (marked in yellow in the picture above) logged out Configuration file found, it does not necessarily mean that the config file logged out in the green part of log is the file found.
But this trap can be avoided by not having a config file named webpack.config.js