# Failed to exec start script when running npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am receiving this error when trying to start my node application using the npm start command.

[image: Error from command prompt]

From log

---

10 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: F:\reactjs

11 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack-dev-server --hot' ]

12 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 4294967295  signal: null

13 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script

14 verbose stack Error: @ start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`

14 verbose stack Exit status 4294967295

14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (E:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)

14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)

14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (E:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)

14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)

14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)

14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)

15 verbose pkgid @

16 verbose cwd F:\reactjs

17 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586

18 error argv "E:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "E:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

19 error node v6.11.3

20 error npm  v3.10.10

21 error code ELIFECYCLE

22 error @ start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`

22 error Exit status 4294967295

23 error Failed at the @ start script 'webpack-dev-server --hot'.

23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,

23 error not with npm itself.

23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:

23 error     webpack-dev-server --hot

23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:

23 error     npm bugs

23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

23 error     npm owner ls

23 error There is likely additional logging output above.

---

Comment: Read the error: *"Configuration file found but no entry configured."*

Comment: looking from your logs it seems you're using webpack. Can you share webpack config and package json contents? Also be more descriptive about what kind of node application it is.

Comment: package.json {
 
  
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
  "scripts": { "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot" } 
}

Comment: config var config = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8082
   },
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
module.exports = config;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in your webpack configuration.

The line that gives you this error is line 4

```
Configuration file found but no entry configured
```

This might help:

[Webpack configuration file found but no entry configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357584/webpack-configuration-file-found-but-no-entry-configured)

here is the docs on webpack for entry: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry

Comment: I just changed the port 8082 to 8081 and it is working fine now . I didn't change any major modifications in configuration files